# How can I know about Memcache status in my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, heroku

I created a Rails app hosted on Heroku with a Memcache plugin limited to 5 MB.

How can I know about Memcache status, free cache left, biggest cache chunk etc.? Can I access this within the app (an admin page for example)? Or using the Ruby console? Also, is there any graphical plugin for this?

Comment: http://barkingiguana.com/2009/03/04/memcache-statistics-from-the-command-line

Comment: @Wrikken, you can post this link and excerpt from the website you linked as an answer.

Comment: Don't actually know Ruby (I did know the memcached TCP protocol though), so I was hesitant posting code I have no way of assuring the quality of code other then: it's the right protocol & it works, but OK, there you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://barkingiguana.com/2009/03/04/memcache-statistics-from-the-command-line

```
require 'socket'

socket = TCPSocket.open('localhost', '11211')
socket.send("stats\r\n", 0)

statistics = []
loop do
  data = socket.recv(4096)
  if !data || data.length == 0
    break
  end
  statistics << data
  if statistics.join.split(/\n/)[-1] =~ /END/
    break
  end
end

puts statistics.join()
```